# Performance difference in Solr for several vs. one filter queries

Tags: http, search, post, solr, filter

Is there any performance or other difference between providing several filter queries as separate `fq` parameters versus providing a single one with all constraints joined with `AND`?

E.g. `fq=field1:foo&fq=field2:bar` vs. `fq=(field1:foo) AND (field2:bar)`

Obviously the first method is more readable and manageable, but I'm sending long queries (suboptimal, but there are reasons for that) via POST, and the library I use doesn't handle POST array parameters very well: they come out as `fq[0]=...&fq[1]=...` which is not recognised by Solr. Hence I consider joining everything into a single `fq` parameter to avoid that and wonder if that has any other consequences apart from being an ugly crutch.

Solr version is 4.5 if that matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have the same result with the 2 queries: 
    `E.g. fq=field1:foo&fq=field2:bar vs. fq=(field1:foo) AND (field2:bar)`

but for performance matters you should prefer to split into many fq your request ! :) It has always been faster for me ! Let me also ask you to [use solr Filters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching#filterCache) they are great to optimise the request speed!  enjoy solr! :)

Comment: Do you know how much is the difference and why? So far I didn't notice much of a difference on my test queries but unsure if that were just particular use cases or not.

Comment: I don't know the root reason of this issue, but in fact I've been testing it on index of 50Millions of docs and 70 Millions of docs. Take a look a this [reference Filter Post](http://searchhub.org/2012/02/10/advanced-filter-caching-in-solr/) to understand the phylosophy of solr. :)